# Deploying Liferay in Virgo( Springsource dm server )

Tags: liferay, springsource-dm-server, eclipse-virgo

I am getting following exception when I tried to deploy liferay war file into Virgo server. Can any one help me please?

```
[2010-11-10 06:24:16.647] start-signalling-3 System.out Loading jar:file:/D:/VGP/Servers/Spike-liferay inside virgo/virgo-web-server-2.1.0.RELEASE/virgo-web-server-2.1.0.RELEASE/work/osgi/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/36/data/store/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/63/1/bundlefile/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.647] start-signalling-3 System.out 06:28:21,553 ERROR [ContextLoader:220] Context initialization failed 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi.manifest.parse.BundleManifestParseException: Error parsing bundle manifest header [JSR 286] 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out HP005W:[col 3]: Unexpected space found 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out HP013E:[col 4]: Expected a semicolon but found '286' 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out at org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi.manifest.parse.standard.StandardHeaderParser.parseBundleSymbolicName(StandardHeaderParser.java:96) 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out at org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi.manifest.internal.StandardBundleSymbolicName.parse(StandardBundleSymbolicName.java:33) 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out at org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi.manifest.internal.BaseParameterised.resetFromParseString(BaseParameterised.java:42) 
[2010-11-10 06:28:21.662] start-signalling-3 System.out at org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi.manifest.internal.StandardBundleManifest.initializeHeaders(StandardBundleManifest.java:118) 
...........
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the MANIFEST.MF is badly formed - there seems to be a space in a manifest header "JSR 286".

Comment: Sorry, looks like thats not the issue

Comment: I see. Then it's probably best to ask on the Virgo forum where the Virgo users hang out.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested http://sourceforge.net/projects/liferayforvirgo